# Camelot switches characters around

Tags: python, python-camelot

I'm trying to parse tables in a PDF using Camelot. The cells have multiple lines of texts in them, and some have an empty line separating portions of the text:

```
First line
Second line

Third line
```

I would expect this to be parsed as `First line\nSecond line\n\nThird line` (notice the double line breaks), but I get this instead: `T\nFirst line\nSecond line\nhird line`. The first character after a double-line-break moves to the beginning of the text, and I only get a single line-break instead.

I also tried using tabula, but that one messes up de entire table (data-frame actually) when there is an empty row in the table, and also in case of some words it puts a space between the characters.

**EDIT:**

My main issue is the removal of multiple line-breaks. The other one I could fix from code if I knew where the empty lines were.

Comment: It's hard to interpret what has gone wrong, without looking into the actual PDF. May be PDF has a big white space?

Comment: The buggy part, with the moving of the first letter seems to be pdf-dependent. But the line-breaks are always reduced to a single one.

Answer (score 1):

my friend, can you check the example here

https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#improve-guessed-table-rows

tables = camelot.read_pdf('group_rows.pdf', flavor='stream', row_tol=10)

tables[0].df

I solved the same problem with the code below

tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, flavor = 'stream', table_areas=['24,618,579,93'], columns=['67,315,369,483,571'], row_tol=10,strip_text='t\r\n\v')

Comment: I need to make it work with lattice. The stream flavor would detect the empty lines, but it's not as accurate overall, and I need to have the entire row of the table in one place

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered the same problem in case of a double line break. It was Switching Characters around as its doing in your case. I Spent some time looking at the code and i did some changes and fixed the issue. You can use the below code.
After Adding the below code, instead of using camelot.read_pdf, use the custom method i made read_pdf_custom()
And for a better experience, i suggest you using camelot v==0.8.2

```
import sys
import warnings
from camelot import read_pdf
from camelot import handlers
from camelot.core import TableList
from camelot.parsers import Lattice
from camelot.parsers.base import BaseParser
from camelot.core import Table
import camelot
from camelot.utils import validate_input, remove_extra,TemporaryDirectory,get_page_layout,get_text_objects,get_rotation,is_url,download_url,scale_image,scale_pdf,segments_in_bbox,text_in_bbox,merge_close_lines,get_table_index,compute_accuracy,compute_whitespace

    
    
from camelot.image_processing import (
    adaptive_threshold,
    find_lines,
    find_contours,
    find_joints,
)

class custom_lattice(Lattice):
    def _generate_columns_and_rows(self, table_idx, tk):
        # select elements which lie within table_bbox
        t_bbox = {}
        v_s, h_s = segments_in_bbox(
            tk, self.vertical_segments, self.horizontal_segments
        )
        custom_horizontal_indexes=[]
        custom_vertical_indexes=[]
        for zzz in self.horizontal_text:
            try:
                h_extracted_text=self.find_between(str(zzz),"'","'").strip()
                h_text_index=self.find_between(str(zzz),"LTTextLineHorizontal","'").strip().split(",")
                custom_horizontal_indexes.append(h_text_index[1])
            except:
                pass



        inserted=0
        for xxx in self.vertical_text:
            v_extracted_text=self.find_between(str(xxx),"'","'").strip()
            v_text_index=self.find_between(str(xxx),"LTTextLineVertical","'").strip().split(",")
            custom_vertical_indexes.append(v_text_index[1])
            vertical_second_index=v_text_index[1]
            try:
                horizontal_index=custom_horizontal_indexes.index(vertical_second_index)
                self.horizontal_text.insert(horizontal_index,xxx)
            except Exception as exxx:
                pass
        self.vertical_text=[]
        t_bbox["horizontal"] = text_in_bbox(tk, self.horizontal_text)
        t_bbox["vertical"] = text_in_bbox(tk, self.vertical_text)

        t_bbox["horizontal"].sort(key=lambda x: (-x.y0, x.x0))
        t_bbox["vertical"].sort(key=lambda x: (x.x0, -x.y0))

        self.t_bbox = t_bbox

        cols, rows = zip(*self.table_bbox[tk])
        cols, rows = list(cols), list(rows)
        cols.extend([tk[0], tk[2]])
        rows.extend([tk[1], tk[3]])
        cols = merge_close_lines(sorted(cols), line_tol=self.line_tol)
        rows = merge_close_lines(sorted(rows, reverse=True), line_tol=self.line_tol)
        cols = [(cols[i], cols[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(cols) - 1)]
        rows = [(rows[i], rows[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(rows) - 1)]

        return cols, rows, v_s, h_s
    
    
    def _generate_table(self, table_idx, cols, rows, **kwargs):
        print("\n")
        v_s = kwargs.get("v_s")
        h_s = kwargs.get("h_s")
        if v_s is None or h_s is None:
            raise ValueError("No segments found on {}".format(self.rootname))

        table = Table(cols, rows)
        table = table.set_edges(v_s, h_s, joint_tol=self.joint_tol)
        table = table.set_border()
        table = table.set_span()


        pos_errors = []
        for direction in ["vertical", "horizontal"]:
            for t in self.t_bbox[direction]:
                indices, error = get_table_index(
                    table,
                    t,
                    direction,
                    split_text=self.split_text,
                    flag_size=self.flag_size,
                    strip_text=self.strip_text,
                )
                if indices[:2] != (-1, -1):
                    pos_errors.append(error)
                    indices = Lattice._reduce_index(
                        table, indices, shift_text=self.shift_text
                    )
                    for r_idx, c_idx, text in indices:
                        temp_text=text.strip().replace("\n","")
                        if len(temp_text)==1:
                            text=temp_text

                        table.cells[r_idx][c_idx].text = text
        accuracy = compute_accuracy([[100, pos_errors]])
        if self.copy_text is not None:
            table = Lattice._copy_spanning_text(table, copy_text=self.copy_text)

        data = table.data
        table.df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        table.shape = table.df.shape

        whitespace = compute_whitespace(data)
        table.flavor = "lattice"
        table.accuracy = accuracy
        table.whitespace = whitespace
        table.order = table_idx + 1
        table.page = int(os.path.basename(self.rootname).replace("page-", ""))

        # for plotting
        _text = []
        _text.extend([(t.x0, t.y0, t.x1, t.y1) for t in self.horizontal_text])
        _text.extend([(t.x0, t.y0, t.x1, t.y1) for t in self.vertical_text])
        table._text = _text
        table._image = (self.image, self.table_bbox_unscaled)
        table._segments = (self.vertical_segments, self.horizontal_segments)
        table._textedges = None

        return table
        
class PDFHandler(handlers.PDFHandler):
    def parse(
        self, flavor="lattice", suppress_stdout=False, layout_kwargs={}, **kwargs
    ):

        tables = []
        with TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
            for p in self.pages:
                self._save_page(self.filepath, p, tempdir)
            pages = [
                os.path.join(tempdir, f"page-{p}.pdf") for p in self.pages
            ]
            parser = custom_lattice(**kwargs) if flavor == "lattice" else Stream(**kwargs)
            for p in pages:
                t = parser.extract_tables(
                    p, suppress_stdout=suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs=layout_kwargs
                )
                tables.extend(t)
        return TableList(sorted(tables))

    

def read_pdf_custom(
    filepath,
    pages="1",
    password=None,
    flavor="lattice",
    suppress_stdout=False,
    layout_kwargs={},
    **kwargs
):

    if flavor not in ["lattice", "stream"]:
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "Unknown flavor specified." " Use either 'lattice' or 'stream'"
        )

    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        if suppress_stdout:
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

        validate_input(kwargs, flavor=flavor)
        p = PDFHandler(filepath, pages=pages, password=password)
        kwargs = remove_extra(kwargs, flavor=flavor)
        tables = p.parse(
            flavor=flavor,
            suppress_stdout=suppress_stdout,
            layout_kwargs=layout_kwargs,
            **kwargs
        )
        return tables
```